# Stripe change payment method if first one not available

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, webhooks

I have my stripe payment up and working.

I use it with Learnybox platform, this is an e-learning platform, I host it and setup everything to give online class to my users.

I sell these lessons on a subscription model. Learnybox platform sends PaymentIntent to my stripe account and charge the customer every month.

It works well; except when a user wants to change his card or when his card expired.

The problem is when a user updated or add a new card on stripe, learnybox payment intent keeps asking for the old payment method.

Webhook is the only way to use stripe with learnybox.

So because I cannot configure stripe payment intent on learnybox servers , **I was wondering is there a way to tell stripe to charge an other payment method if the one asked for is not available ?**

For instance expired card but there's an other payment method available because user added an other card when I notified the first card was expired, can I charge the new card ?

For information, the user goes trough my website when he wants to update his card.

I have tried to catch the payment intent and change it but this is too much trouble and not safe in my opinion. Any similar experiences ?

I have also tried to delete the old card and leaving only the new card but payment still fails.

**Is the solution to create a webhook on my server that track the payment intent status and try to change the payment method if it fails ?**

Comment: Stripe will only charge the specific PaymentMethod you tell it to, by passing its ID to the API, you can't configure a fallback. So it seems like you(or this platform) needs to build a way to change the PaymentMethod ID that is passed when creating the PaymentIntent.

Comment: Even If recreate a new payment_intent once I know the first failed ?

Comment: Right now I am trying to catch the payment intent status, if it fails update it with a different payment method . If it doesn't work I thought about recreating a payment intent from there

Comment: @karllekko, what about charging the default card if the card asked for in the payment intent doesn't work ? Does stripe allows that ?

Comment: Technically yes. You just re-confirm the PaymentIntent with a new PaymentMethod. https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm

Comment: So technically, If I do a webhook that catch payments intents -> Check if it failed -> change PaymentMethod -> re-confirm the PaymentItent it should be fine ?

Comment: with this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#webhooks

Comment: That should work yes.